# How Do i add colour to this image texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, color

[image]I think i have bumped it correctly? I now want to add colour so that the planet looks nice. Also I am having trouble with the image texture after unwrapping and scaling in the uv image editor- not sure how to fix this? As shown in pics. Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seA1S.png)

I have attatched a detail of the updated nodes, although I cant see the colour option the same as shown in your multiply nodes.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do it like in this example. your uv maps must be wrong unwrapped tho. [image]

Comment: I cannot seem to recreate your nodes as my multiply nodes don't have the colour option? Sorry I am a beginner, thanks for your help

Comment: Instead of your math node set to multiply, use a color mix node like this example set to multiply

Comment: @CraigDJones LOL it its a color node, math node node looks almost similar to that one... btw i have a question to u,  i saw that you get a copy for free of bpainter, how can i get one xD?

Comment: I was talking about the example OP posted having math nodes instead of color mix nodes like yours - and I do not have a free BPainter, I paid for a year on patreon to support it but now I don't use it, it is not 2.8 ready.

Comment: @CraigDJones ok xD